# C++ overloaded operator= does not work properly

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm developing a custom Queue List class in C++.
In my main I have:

```
  QueueLst<int> q1;
  q1.Enqueue(1);
  q1.Enqueue(2);
  q1.Enqueue(3);
  cout<<q1.HeadAndDequeue()<<" "<<q1.HeadAndDequeue()<<" "<<q1.HeadAndDequeue();
```

that works fine, result:

```
1 2 3
```

Now if I write;

```
  QueueLst<int> q1;
  q1.Enqueue(1);
  q1.Enqueue(2);
  q1.Enqueue(3);
  QueueLst<int> q2;
  q2 = q1;
  cout<<q2.HeadAndDequeue()<<" "<<q2.HeadAndDequeue()<<" "<<q2.HeadAndDequeue();
```

output:

```
1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  List is empty!
```

And this is my `operator=` method:

```
template <typename Data>
QueueLst<Data>& QueueLst<Data>::operator=(const QueueLst& toCopy){
   QueueLst<Data>* tmp = new QueueLst<Data>(toCopy);
   std::swap(*this, *tmp);
   delete tmp;
   return *this;
}
```

And I'm 100% sure the copy consructor works fine, in fact, if I write

```
template <typename Data>
QueueLst<Data>& QueueLst<Data>::operator=(const QueueLst& toCopy){
   QueueLst<Data>* tmp = new QueueLst<Data>(toCopy);
   return *tmp;
}
```

It works fine! So there is something strange in the std::swap but how?
I'm sorry that this is a very specific question but can't figure out how to fix that, thank you.

**Update**
Definition of QueueLst:

```
#include "../queue.hpp"
#include "../../list/list.hpp"

namespace lasd {

template <typename Data>
class QueueLst :  virtual public Queue<Data>,
                  virtual protected List<Data>{ // Must extend Queue<Data> and List<Data>

private:

protected:

  using List<Data>::head;
  using List<Data>::tail;
  using List<Data>::size;
  using typename List<Data>::Node;

public:

  // Default constructor
  QueueLst() = default;


  // Specific constructor
  QueueLst(const LinearContainer<Data>&); // A queue obtained from a LinearContainer


  // Copy constructor
  QueueLst(const QueueLst&);

  // Move constructor
  QueueLst(QueueLst&&) noexcept;


  // Destructor
  ~QueueLst();


  // Copy assignment
  QueueLst& operator=(const QueueLst&);

  // Move assignment
  QueueLst& operator=(QueueLst&&) noexcept;


  // Comparison operators
  bool operator==(const QueueLst&) const noexcept;
  bool operator!=(const QueueLst&) const noexcept;


  // Specific member functions (inherited from Queue)

  void Enqueue(const Data&) override; // Override Queue member (copy of the value)
  void Enqueue(Data&&) override; // Override Queue member (move of the value)
  Data& Head() const override; // Override Queue member (must throw std::length_error when empty)
  void Dequeue() override; // Override Queue member (must throw std::length_error when empty)
  Data HeadNDequeue() override; // Override Queue member (must throw std::length_error when empty)


  // Specific member functions (inherited from Container)

  void Clear() override; // Override Container member

};

}

#include "queuelst.cpp"

#endif
```

Comment: You should include the definition for `QueueLst`.

Comment: Have you move assignment/constructor? Think about what `std::swap` does...

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I do! Honestly std::swap() from my point of view is simply a "tmp = a; a=b; b=tmp;", I mean, I don't know its implementation to be honest.

Comment: missing some `std::move` on the right side, but do you see the recursion with `a=b;`? it would be `a = std::move(b);`, but if you don't provide move, it fallbacks to copy.

Comment: BTW, no need of `new`/`delete`, `QueueLst<Data> tmp(toCopy);` would do the job (except in second (test) version).

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Avoid `#include "queuelst.cpp"`. Rename your `.cpp` file to `.hxx` or `.tcc`.

Comment: Thank you @ted-lyngmo but it would be pretty long, is it okay?

Comment: @AlessandroF: I think you can replicate the issue with a simple `struct S {int* p;};` with copy/move contructor/assignement, destructor.

Comment: You're 100% certain your copy constructor works fine.   I'm 100% certain it is not fine, since it gives a memory leak.    Get out of the habit of using a `new` expression when all you need is a temporary - This is C++, not Java or C#.

Comment: @AlessandroF If you make it minimal, it shouldn't need to be _that_ long. Long-ish perhaps, but it'd make it easier for us to pinpoint bugs.

Comment: You are using C++ so I recommend you to use STL-Functions like std::copy for that. These are implemented as a template too, so you have no problem when using them.